How to render a list of pure pdf links
I'm lost trying to find helpful documentation.
I'm on a Liferay DXP quarterly release (2023.q4.0 a.t.m.)
My scenario is:

goal: render a list of pure pdf links (pdf file links) from documents and media
all pdfs are uploaded in a root folder of documents and media, let's say folder name myfolder
update: it's a daily upload of a new pdf, so rendering the link list should be dynamic based on the current content of myfolder. The newest 5 or 10 files would be nice.
urls according to liferay documents and media would for example be (friendly url) /documents/d/guest/<document name> or (webdav url) /webdav/guest/document_library/myfolder/<pdf file name>
every tool would be fine, I'd prefer a design fragment
it's intranet, should be displayable for guest users (not logged in)

